# Use of DUP in assembly language

Tags: assembly, masm, tasm

```
PASSWORD DB 20 DUP(0)
 INPUTSTR DB 20 DUP(0)
```

I was going through a code and I came across this, what does DUP mean in this case? Can anyone explain me. Please! Thanks